# Why isn't my initial value getting set for my Django form?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Here are the relevant snippets

**forms.py**

```
usersegment = [['non-paying','Non-paying (Coming soon)'],['paying','Paying (Coming soon)'], ['all', 'All']]

class SegmentForm(forms.Form):
    usersegment = forms.ChoiceField(label="", widget=RadioSelect(), choices=usersegment)
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'GET' and 'datestart' in request.GET:

    return render_to_response('activation/activation_signupcount.html', 
                            {   'datestart': request.GET['datestart'], 
                                'dateend': request.GET['dateend'], 
                                'usersegment': request.GET['usersegment'], 
                                'form': SegmentForm(request.GET), 
                                'form2': DateSelectForm(request.GET)    })
else:

    return render_to_response('activation/activation_signupcount.html', 
                            {'form': SegmentForm(initial={'all':'All'}), 'form2': DateSelectForm()})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

initials are key:value (fieldname/value) pair. it should go like this,

```
else:
    return render_to_response('activation/activation_signupcount.html', 
              {'form': SegmentForm(initial={'usersegment':'all'}), 
               'form2': DateSelectForm()
              })
```

Comment: ok that makes a lot more sense. I wish someone would say key:value in the other SO answers. Thanks for that. I guess a more better programmer would have figured it out from looking at the braces.

Comment: btw, is there anywhere on the forms.py I can set this so I dont have to repeat `initial={'usersegment':'all'}` for all of my views? I tried appending it like `usersegment = forms.ChoiceField(label="", widget=RadioSelect(), choices=usersegment, initial={'usersegment':'all'})` but it doesnt work. Thanks.

Comment: yes, usersegment = forms.ChoiceField(initial='all' label="", widget=RadioSelect(), choices=usersegment)